# Visualforcepage security

Tags: visualforce, security, profile

I have a custom profile named Marketing Team and the assigned user is Sujal.
In that profile, i enabled one visualforce page access to him. So accordingly, Sujal can now access that VF page. I have created VF tab of that page. When i log in to Sujal's id, he is able to access that tab that shows the page output, but when i go to the pages, he is able to view all the pages, though i have given him access to only one page in profile plus he isn't able to delete or clone or edit or preview any of the pages not even the page he has given access to.
It's showing insufficient priviledges.

Comment: I read the Vf page security. Customize application will allow user to edit all the pages that i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

There are separate mechanisms for being able to execute (see the results of) a Visualforce page (see [Visualforce Page Security Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_page_level_security.htm&language=en_US)) and being able to edit a Visualforce page (see [Viewing and Editing Visualforce Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_edit.htm)). Generally, ordinary end-users of your system would not be given the "Customize Application" permission that allows the editing to be done.

Comment: I have given him read, edit access

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that the user has access to the object behind your page[image: You will want to give read, Create, Edit and delete]

Comment: I have given him read, edit access to the object

Comment: Any connected objects, Controllers ext

Comment: I have used only standard controller in my VF page.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="CDs__c">
<br> price of cd :{!CDs__c.price__c}</br>
<br> quantity of cd: {!CDs__c.quantity__c}</br>
<br> name of the cd: {!CDs__c.name}</br>
 
</apex:page>

Comment: Above is the VF page. I give access to that user by going through the assigned profile and enable VF page access. But when i log in to this user, the user can't edit or clone or preview the page but can view all pages.

Comment: Have you assigned the Profile to us the correct page layout, As if you have created a new layout you will need to assign this to the profile.
other then that put your debug statements on and trace where that came from.

Comment: Yes i have assigned to correct page layout.